# PHP onSubmit, JS function will not execute

Tags: javascript, php, html, onsubmit

I am still new to PHP and JS, but from what I have been reading on, when a form has an **onSubmit** element, then the form requires a `return true` from the function in order to execute the submission.
I cannot get this to work however.

Can someone help me figure out what my problem is? I also added a random `alert()` at the beginning of the Javascript function and that does not go off either.

Thank you!

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>


<script type="text/javascript">

function Validate(){
    alert("validating..");
    var min=document.forms["myForm"]["minWeight"].value;
    var max=document.forms["myForm"]["maxWeight"].value;

if (min < max)
  {
      return true;
  }
  else 
  {
  alert("Minimum weight " + min + " is not lower than " + max " Maximum weight");
      return false;
  }
}
</script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>

<form name="myForm" action="page2.php" method="post"  onSubmit="return Validate()">
    <p><label>Enter minimum weight: <input type="number" name="minWeight" value="0" min="0" required /></label></p>
    <p><label>Enter maximum weight: <input type="number" name="maxWeight" value="999" min="0" max="999" required /></label></p>
    <p>Select gender:
        <label><input type="radio" name="genderType" value="male" required /> Male</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="genderType" value="female" /> Female</label>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: FYI, it doesn't require `return true;`, it just requires that it _not_ have `return false;` or call `event.preventDefault()`. If it returns something other than false, or if it has no `return` statement at all, the default action will take place.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your javascript:

```
alert("Minimum weight " + min + " is not lower than " + max " Maximum weight");
                                                          ^^^
```

Change it to:

```
alert("Minimum weight " + min + " is not lower than " + max + " Maximum weight");
```

and it should work, see the [example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qanepice/1).

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you very much! I will mark as answer when the timer goes away. :)